# Count How many number multiple by the number from input user between a range

Tags: java

again I have a problem with doing practice prepare for the exam.
Would everyone help me? Thanks a lot

> write a program input an integer in the range 100 to 200 inclusive.  If the user enters invalid input then your algorithm should re-prompt the user until the input is valid.  Your algorithm should then count how many numbers between 500 and 1000 which are multiples of the number input.  Finally, the count should be output to the user.  You should make good use of sub-modules.

Here my code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exam3
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int count = 0;
        int input = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter number: ");
            input = sc.nextInt();

           while(input < 100 || input > 200)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number between 100 to 200");
                input = sc.nextInt();

                count ++;

            }   
          System.out.println("count is: " + count);     
    }
    public static void int getCount(int input, int count)
    {
        for(int i = 499;i <= 1000; i++ )
        {
                if(i % input==0)
                {
                    count++;
                }            
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your Problem with the code?

Comment: Just saying, I like that you ask for a number "between 200 to 300" but check for `input < 100 || input > 200`. But for any problem, you should first call `getCount`. Also, you could check with a better solution than iteration thought 500 values by simply using the input received directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm should be:

Having correct input, find all multiples of it that are in range [500, 1000]. Count them.

It's a bad approach to check all the numbers, as we know from our math knowledge, that between `k*a` and `k*a + a` there is no number divisible by `a`.

Knowing that and having `input` we enlarge our `temp` initialized with value of `input` by `input`. If it's in range `[500, 1000]` we enlarge our counter. Simple as that.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int count = 0;
    int input = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    input = sc.nextInt();

    while (input < 100 || input > 200) {
        System.out.println("Enter number between 100 to 200");
        input = sc.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(input + " fits " + count(input) + " times");
}


private static int count(int input) {
    int result = 0;
    int temp = input;
    while (temp <= 1000) {
        if (temp >= 500) {
            result++;
        }
        temp += input;
    }
    return result;
}
```

According to your code, I see some issues. I'll point them out, as it is important for practicing Java.

- Method can be either `void` or return `int`. You can't have `void int`. In this case, we return `int`, so `int` is the return type,
- It's important to stick to Java styling. Don't put too many empty lines, keep indents.
- Use `Eclipse` or `IntelliJ` (`IntelliJ` is more pro). They will point unused code blocks, so you would know that that `getCount` wasn't called.

Comment: I upvote because of the note on the mathematic approach. it just demand to find the first value then increment by "input" until a certain point (condition)

Comment: @AxelH I decided to put this code here, being afraid, that the solution with modulo will be the most popular one.

Comment: Nice approach however this can be solved in `O(1)` for any input.

Comment: @xenteros I totaly agree with you, even if it works with a modulo, a correct solution would only need 5 incrementation to find every value (as the minimum value is 100), compared to 500 incrementation.

Comment: @SanketMakani yes, I agree that it's possible to divide 500 per input, but I was to lazy to conciser edge cases :) Also, this solution is also O(1) :)

Comment: @xenteros Yup but I have added my approach as an answer. :)